# Debugging a Application Launch in Xcode and iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have a very specific case that I need to debug.  I need to examine what is happening when an application is relaunched after being killed (looking at what stored data is being read, etc.).  If I kill the application from the device, the debugger stops (which makes sense).

The best method I can think of is killing the application, and re-launching from Xcode (without modifying any code).  I am trying to investigate "real world" behaviour.   Is this the best approach for my case, or is there another way to view what happening with Xcode?

Comment: Are you talking about quiting the app(double tap home button and hit minus icon) or suspending it to the background (just hitting home button)

Comment: @adam0101 Yes.  I kill the app by double tapping the home button and stopping the application manually.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the Scheme editor in Xcode, you can edit the Debug profile to have the debugger "Wait for XY.app to launch". If you then select Product -> Run, the debugger should wait until you launch the app manually on the device and then automatically attach to the running process.

Comment: Is it safe to assume all data stored to the Documents directory and NSUserDefaults is preserved (assuming I don't modify any code)?

Comment: Yes, I would definitely say so.

Comment: Does it work on simulator? I found that it don't. It doesn't move the executable to the simulator.

Comment: Please also keep this bug in mind: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4983181564444672

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the build & run phase altogether / changing build configs, you can achieve a cold-start reattach by:

- going to Debug menu > `Attach to Process by PID or Name...`
- putting your app name in the first input & clicking `Attach`

You'll then see "Waiting to attach to APPNAME on somedevice", and you can just reopen the app on the simulator.

Answer (score -1):

**Xcode debug app after launch**

1. -> Run -> Info -> Wait for the executable to be launched

[image]

2. Debug -> Attach to Process by PID or Name... -> <app_name> -> Attach

[image]

after that you will see in Debug navigator that debugger is waiting for attach(if app is removed from memory)

[image]