# App crash when return from the background

Tags: ios, swift

My app creates a large database in the user's first lgin. It took me about 2 minutes to create this bank. When I'm in the middle of this process and I go home to the app and right after I touch the app again it displays a part of the last screen and then breaks. This problem seems to be simple to solve, but I can not debug because it only happens on the device and only when it is not debugging. When I'm debugging the application it just continues the process from where it stopped. What could be wrong? I'll attach my AppDelegate if it helps.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

        let applicationFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let window = UIWindow(frame: applicationFrame)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

        let tutorialIntroduced = self.defaults.bool(forKey: "tutorialIntroduced")

        if !tutorialIntroduced {
            presentTutorial()

        } else {
            if (Auth.auth().currentUser) != nil {

                if self.defaults.object(forKey: "completeDB") == nil {
                    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "SignIn", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DBCreatingViewController") as! DBCreatingViewController
                    self.window?.rootViewController = vc

                } else {
                    if self.defaults.bool(forKey: "completeDB") == true {
                        presentHome()
                    } else {
                        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "SignIn", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DBCreatingViewController") as! DBCreatingViewController
                        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
                    }
                }

            } else {
                presentSignIn()
            }
        }

        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Message ID \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
```

Comment: You can attach your xcode after the app launch to debug by changing a param in the debug scheme called `wait for executable to be launched`by default is selected `automatically` , also you can add Fabric or some other crash reporter to help you

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Do what? debug your app or add fabric?

Comment: Debug my app this way. When I debug using the device the crash does not happen. The fabric I know the most I need to fix this soon and use on screen would be more time consuming.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208665/debugging-a-application-launch-in-xcode-and-ios